# How to theme each field of exposed filter from Views?

Tags: theming, views

I have found the theme template for exposed filter form of view.
Template name: `views-exposed-form.tpl.php`

Inside the template I found the `$widgets array` and `for loop` for each `$widget` display in form.

But it is rendered HTML widget How can I get only values array for each combo box to render output for my combo box as I want?

for instance:

I have one combo called Country:
Country has hierarchy level of list

```
Asia
- India
- Sri lanka
- thailand
- Indonesia
```

etc...

So, I would like to make my combo just like this

```
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tryit.asp?filename=tryhtml_optgroup

<select>
  <optgroup label="Swedish Cars">
    <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
    <option value="saab">Saab</option>
  </optgroup>
  <optgroup label="German Cars">
    <option value="mercedes">Mercedes</option>
    <option value="audi">Audi</option>
  </optgroup>
</select>
```

This will identify the parent / child category in combo?
can we do this directly in drupal 7 Views for Expoesd Filters Combo ?
or
How can I theme myself to override its HTML?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try to catch it with `hook_form_alter()`: `$form_id` is views_exposed_form, and `$form` contains all the values.

```
$form['field_custom']['#options'] = array(
  'group1' => array('key11' => 'value11', 'key12' => 'value12'),
  'group2' => array('key21' => 'value21', 'key22' => 'value22' ),
);
```

Comment: I have check with $form_id == "views_exposed_form";

after that I want to replace the value of Select Options array to Group Select Options but will not replace How Can I replace the value of Select Options in theme_form_alter method

Comment: The `hook_form_alter()` is in custom module not in the theme. You can also use devel module and dpm() function to display what the $form variable contains. You can alter the values with : $form['field_custom']['#options']

Comment: What is the structure of ARRAY I can pass to $form['field_custom']['#options']

Comment: Display the original struture with using devel module and dpm function, you'll see how is the actual structure ot the array. For a select list with groups, look at the updated answer above

Comment: Hey, @pico34 it is working but there is one problem to identify the parent child option.

I have do this in custom module

`if($form_id == "views_exposed_form") 
{
   print_r( $form['field_geography_countries_tid']['#options'] );

}`

> This will return an array single dimension so, How can I check that which options are parent/child

Comment: I have load the taxonomy based on tid and update the above given array structure it is very much helpful. thank you.

Comment: taxonomy_get_tree() can help you to rebuild your needed options

Comment: please you can help me how to rebuild options from Taxonomy term of given any vocabulary_machine_name.
It should be generalize function of any level of parent/child relationship terms. to generate the select combo.

and one more thing is it possible to we can Select the Parent Item also.

Comment: Build the array with php this is not drupal specific. The array's target structure is the one i've post in my answer above. Try to focus this goal

Answer (score 0):

You can control everything at different levels, with the "views-exposed-form" template, and editing the widgets' HTML code in the "theme_preprocess_views_exposed_form".

I wrote a post on how to do this in my blog:   <s>http://danyalejandro.com/portafolio/content/theming-exposed-filters-drupal-7-views</s>

[Theming exposed filters in Drupal 7 Views (Web Archive Retrieved)](http://web.archive.org/web/20150306173528/http://danyalejandro.com/portafolio/content/theming-exposed-filters-drupal-7-views)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [Views exposed form layout](https://www.drupal.org/project/vefl) module may help you.